# Renaming file with nodejs

Tags: node.js, file

I'm trying to rename a file, and I think I'm going mad my code is simple, I check if the file exists, and if it exists, I rename it. Here is the code :

```
if (fs.existsSync(__dirname+"/"+req.files.file.path))
{
    fs.rename(__dirname+"/"+req.files.file.path, __dirname+"/app/upload/portfolio/video/"+req.files.file.name, function(err) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        else
            ....
    });
}
```

But I get this error (I've replaced the realpath by path/to/file) :

> throw err;
>                         ^
>   Error: ENOENT, rename 'path/to/file/filename.mp4'

After a check, I see that the file exists (simply by copy/paste the filepath in the error)
What can be the reason of such an issue?

Comment: Are the privileges set right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rename` can fail with `ENOENT` not only if the source doesn’t exist, but also if the directory of the destination doesn’t exist. I suspect `app/upload/portfolio/video/path/to/file` does not exist.